# Application Deployment will not deploy to my Windows 7.8 Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a lumia 800 Windows 7.8 phone.

I am trying to deploy some apps through "XapDeploy.exe" but it won't work. I tried a demo project from the internet as well as a project I made.

I try to deploy the .xap file and it just fails.

I tried different usb ports, disabling windows firewall but nothing works.

I am on windows 7 64bit.

> Error - A connection attempt faile because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Zune see's my phone and can sync between the 2.

Comment: Is the phone developer unlocked?

Comment: Ya I registered it. I uninstalled zune, and the entire sdk and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same problem or similiar to one I had.
The solution for my problem was really easy, I just had to disable WLAN and connect the phone again.

If this doens't help, try putting it into airplane mode and/or restarting the phone and/or zune.

Using WPConnect.exe instead of Zune might also help

Hope this helps